# Error: Incompatible element type for collection

Tags: apex

I am trying to create a class using the following code but getting error: 
" Incompatible element type String for collection of listex.s "

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="listex">
<apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list}" var="a">
         <apex:column value="{!a.numb}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.str}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class listex {
    public list<s> inte;
    public integer numb;
    public string str;

    public list<s> getlist(){
        list<s> inte = new list<s>();
        for(integer i=0;i<3;i++) {
            inte.add(numb=i,str='name'+i);
            return inte;
        }
    }

    public class s{
        public integer numb;
        public string str;
        public s(integer i, string s){
            this.numb = i;
            this.str = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this line

```
inte.add(numb=i,str='name'+i);
```

you are trying to add an element of type `s` to the collection `inte` but you need to call the constructor as part of the list add

```
inte.add(new s(i,'name'+i);
```

Comment: Hi, After making that change, I am getting error: "Unknown property 'listex.s.numb'"

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Forgot to add get,set inside class.

Comment: this is presumably a VF error?  In your inner class `s`, the members that are exposed to the VF page need to be declared with {get; set;}

Answer (score 2):

Your next problem is that you need getters and setters on your wrapper class. Try this:

```
public class s{
    public integer numb {get;set;}
    public string str {get;set;}
    public s(integer i, string s){
        this.numb = i;
        this.str = s;
    }
}
```